# JSON echo opening new tab

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm having a really odd problem and iv'e been going at it for a while now, scouring the internet for answers and not finding any. I'm trying to parse a JSON object (which has been successful so far) but the problem I have is that when I link to my HTML file it opens a new tab after clicking submit on the HTML form part. Im sure that this is a stupid question but i really haven't found an answer to it. I'm using PHP to encode a simple JSON object. Here is my code for the HTML part:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<HTML>
<body>
<center>
<H1> Registration </H1>
<form action = "/Register.php" method = "post">
<h2>Username:</h2>
<input type = "text" name = "username"><br>
<h2>Name:</h2>
<input type = "text" name = "name"><br>
<h2>Password:</h2>
<input type = "password" name = "password"><br>
<h2>Age:</h2>
<input type = "number" name = "age"><br><br>
<input type = "submit" name = "Submit">
</form><br>
<a href = "index.html"> Back To Login </a>
<p id = "demo"></p>
<script>
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = myObj.success;
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "Register.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();

</script>
</center>
</body>
</HTML>
```

And here is the code for the php/json part:

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id5137223_bellevueeast", "BEAST", "id5137223_users");

    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $age = $_POST["age"];
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO Users (name, username, age, password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssis", $name, $username, $age, $password);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    $response = array();
    $response["success"] = true;  

    echo json_encode($response);

    ?>
```

Comment: What exactly is the question? Is it _Why does the page navigate to a new page (new tab) when I click submit_? or is it _I am unable to display the JSON data from the XHR in the `p` tag_?

Comment: You're not sending any POST parameters in `xmlhttp.send()`.

Comment: @Barmar - its a GET request - it **should be** a POST request, but I'm not sure what the question is.

Comment: Are you trying to find out how to submit the form using AJAX?

Comment: I guess my question is what Randy Casburn said best: Why does the page navigate to a new page (new tab) when I click submit? to elaborate on that, it specifically gives me back my JSON response, which is { "success" : true }

Comment: The problem lies not within the JSON, JSON doesn't have to do with anything that is moving pages related. What you are trying to do here not moving pages using AJAX. Am I saying it correctly @GavinVanOrnum?

Comment: @GavinVanOrnum I can't see any reason why it should go to a new tab when you submit. It should replace the current tab with the JSON in the response.

Comment: If you had `target="_blank"` in the `<form>` it would open the response in a new tab.

Comment: @barmar so if I changed the target to something else, it might be fixed?

Comment: No. When you leave out `target`, it opens in the same tab. That's why I don't see how it's opening a new tab.

Comment: @barmar ah, i see

Comment: You can do `target="_self"`, but this is the same as leaving it out entirely.

Comment: I honestly only used the ajax in the javascript to try and fix this problem (which obviously didn't work), before it had done the same thing, just without the javascript to parse it.

Comment: @Brad yeah I know, but I am doing this for a school project and my first priority is getting the dang thing to work, from there I am going to encrypt it etc. but this thing has to be completely done by thursday next week, after that I will be polishing it.

Comment: Are you using stupid `IE` ?  `header('Content-type: application/json')`  Sometime Internet Explorer will try to download Json response because it thinks it's a `.txt` file.  Even if you don't tell it to download.

Answer (score 0):

It's opening a new window/tab because you are not preventing the default behavior of the HTML form, which will submit to it's own location. Basically it sends a request to the page the form is on with the get/post data from the form attached. Your JavaScript function executes fine, but then the default action of the form causes a second window to open.

If you do not want this to happen, you have to break or stop the default behavior of the HTML form with prevent default.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your code, I am guessing that you want to call a JSON from Register.php and display it on the same page. In this case, what you need to do is to encase you XMLRequest in a Javascript function like so

```
function showResult() {
//do your XMLRequest stuff here
//change the div accordingly
document.getElementById("placeholder").innerHTML=*prettified json here*;
}
```

Then what you need to do is create a div to show your results and act as a placeholder

```
<div id="placeholder">
```

Next up is to change the submit into a button and add onPress="showResult()" to it.

```
<button onPress="showResult()">
```

You don't need submit if you are using AJAX

Answer (score 0):

WOW. I realized that I am, in fact, an idiot.  I was diagnosing the problem completely wrong.  I thought that the form was acting up when in fact it was doing exactly what it was supposed to: Showing the data in the tab after the form went through. I finally got to do what I wanted it to though by doing this:

```
<iframe id="invisible" name="invisible" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

and then I made the form target the iframe so it would not display anything
-_- sorry for troubling you all.